# How to fetch value of a Dropdown option in Angular form

Tags: angular, typescript, free

I'm creating a custom form. I've created a custom form:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(contactForm)" #contactForm="ngForm">
  ....email input filed
  <label class="label" for="experience">How did you find the booking experience?</label>
  <select id="experience" #experience="ngModel"[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
        <option value="verygood">Very good</option>
        <option value="good">Good</option>
        <option value="fair">Fair</option>
        <option value="poor">Poor</option>
      </select>
    <button type="submit " value="Send ">Send</button>
</form>
```

here is the typescript:

```
  onSubmit(contactForm: NgForm) {
    console.log("called");
    if (contactForm.valid) {
      const email = contactForm.value;
      const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      this.http.post('https://formspree.io/f/xnqolzjd',
        { replyto: email.email, experience: email.experience },
        { 'headers': headers }).subscribe(
          response => {
            console.log(response);
          }
        );
    }
  }
```

But my `experience: email.experience` is blank in the object. It works when I hard code some value in the object itself. `replyto: email.email` is fetching correct value. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when we set ngModelOptions to standalone, it will not register with parent form, that's why you getting empty object. Try setting standalone to false and try

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(contactForm)" #contactForm="ngForm">
  ....email input filed
  <label class="label" for="experience">How did you find the booking experience?</label>
  <select id="experience" name="experience" #experience="ngModel" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: false}">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
        <option value="verygood">Very good</option>
        <option value="good">Good</option>
        <option value="fair">Fair</option>
        <option value="poor">Poor</option>
      </select>
    <button type="submit " value="Send ">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What If just remove it instead of making it false. I added it because i was getting this error on console:
`If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set
                      or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.`

Comment: That's also fine for your refrence i have set false, yes you have to set name attribute on form control element.

Comment: Now I'll write unit test cases. We may want to re-open this discussion.